# thread safe unique id generation in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I was looking for thread safe unique id generation in c++ application life, So I have created following static class.

```
class Utils {
public :
    static int getUid();
};

int Utils::getUid() {
    static std::atomic<std::uint32_t> uid;
    uid = 0;
    return ++uid;
}
```

Any suggestion, Is this right approach.

Comment: You might've noticed it returns only `1`.

Comment: Not yet tested, will check with some sample code. Any other approach for getting thing done.

Comment: You keep reseting `uid = 0` on every call, thats all.

Comment: Yes Thanks this works. An uninitialized static variable set to 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fix it this way:

```
class Utils {
public :
    static int getUid();
};

int Utils::getUid() {
    static std::atomic<std::uint32_t> uid { 0 };  // <<== initialised
//    uid = 0;    <<== removed
    return ++uid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. but do we really need to initialise static variable.

Comment: @Sachin yes, we do. It's the only way to give it a value in a thread-safe way. If you wish, you may initialise it with a function, but it must be done as an initialisation, not a subsequent operation.

Comment: So I can assume that even it is local variable. It is thread safe because of atomic.

Comment: @Sachin The *initialisation* is thread-safe because it's static, and c++11 guarantees that static initialisation will be thread-safe. Subsequent access will be thread-safe because it is an atomic.